# Ask user to repeat the program or exit in C

Tags: c, printf

In this very basic program which ask the user to input two numbers, and then the program will sum these numbers together. I want at the end to ask the user if he/she want to repeat the program again or to exit the program! for example if he/she press y the program will reask the user to input two number, otherwise the program will be closed. How to do it ?

```
main(){
float x,y,sum;
printf ("Enter the first number:");
scanf ("%f",&x);
printf ("Enter the second number:");
scanf ("%f",&y);
sum=x+y;
printf ("The total number is:%f",sum);
}
```

Comment: A `while` loop, along  with reading a `char`.

Comment: Your code nested in a do while loop, that's the answer

Comment: You really should spend some time reading some book on C programming, and reading documentation of standard functions like `scanf` & `printf`. Your `main` is wrongly declared. You should enable all warnings & debug info when compiling (`gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`). You should use the debugger. Voting to close your question as a *fix my code* request.

Comment: @yaya, check my answer, it has a tutorial for `do-while` loop. That might help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int main(void) {
float x,y,sum;
char ch;
do {
printf ("Enter the first number:");
scanf ("%f",&x);
printf ("Enter the second number:");
scanf ("%f",&y);
sum=x+y;
printf ("The total number is:%f\n",sum);
printf ("Do you want to repeat the operation Y/N: ");
scanf (" %c", &ch);
}
while (ch == 'y' || ch == 'Y');
}
```

This uses a `do-while` loop. It will continue till the condition in the `while` of the `do-while` will return false.

In simple words, whenever the user enters `y` or `Y`, the `while` loop will return true. Thus, it will continue.

Check [this](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_do_while_loop.htm) example and tutorial for `do-while` loop.

Answer (score 5):

```
main(){
    float x,y,sum;
    char ch;

    do{
    printf ("Enter the first number:");
    scanf ("%f",&x);
    printf ("Enter the second number:");
    scanf ("%f",&y);
    sum=x+y;
    printf ("The total number is:%f",sum);
    printf ("Do you want to continue: y/n");
    scanf (" %c", &ch);
    } while(ch == 'y');
    }
```

OR you can also try this:

```
main(){
    float x,y,sum;
    char ch;

    do{
    printf ("Enter the first number:");
    scanf ("%f",&x);
    printf ("Enter the second number:");
    scanf ("%f",&y);
    sum=x+y;
    printf ("The total number is:%f",sum);
    printf ("Do you want to continue: y/n");
    ch = getchar();
    getchar();
    } while(ch == 'y');
    }
```

Comment: This is not the proper declaration of the `main`. It has to be `int main ()`, `int main (void)` or `int main (int argc, char **argv)`

Comment: @AshishAhuja It's an allowed form in the old C90 standard. It could also be allowed on any C compiler given that the form `main()` is documented by the compiler.

Comment: @Lundin, is it documented by `gcc`?

Comment: @AshishAhuja in C90 when no explicit type of a function is used, int is implicitly used

Comment: @AshishAhuja `-ffreestanding` is properly documented and allows any form. When compiled for hosted (default/`-fhosted`), gcc does not allow `main()` unless you tell it to compile against the old C90 (`-std=c90`) standard. It will then only give a warning.

Answer (score -1):

[In this program I used 'goto' statement because if I use do while loop then if I enter anything without "Y or y" then the program will be close.To avoid this problem I use 'goto' statement.[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8WKMc.png)

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){
float x, y, sum;
char ch;
print:
    printf ("Enter the first number:");
    scanf ("%f",&x);
    printf ("Enter the second number:");
    scanf ("%f",&y);
    sum=x+y;
    printf ("\nThe total number is:%.2f\n",sum);
again:
    printf ("\n\t\t\t\t\tDo you want to repeat the operation(Y/N): ");
    scanf (" %c", &ch);

    if(ch == 'y' || ch == 'Y'){
        goto print;
    }
    else if(ch == 'n' || ch == 'N'){
        return 0;
    }
    else{
        printf("\n\t\t\t\t\tPlease enter Yes or NO.\n");
        goto again;
    }
   return 0;}
```